# how to get erc-1155 totalSupply

Tags: erc-1155

I want to know how many tokenIDs are in an ERC1155 token, how can this be achieved?
I want to know how many tokens are in a specific tokenID, how can this be achieved?
Are there functions in the specifications that allow for that?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could query the events `TransferSingle` and `TransferBatch` and make your calculation for how many tokens are minted. This applies also for your second question. But you always have to look at every implementation separately.